# HP Mini (210-1000SA PC), fan always running

Tags: drivers, lubuntu, hp, fan

After changing the OS from Windows to Lubuntu (15.04), my Netbooks's fan is always running. I think the problem in Drivers. So, I tried to find drivers in offical HP's website but there is no exist driver for ubuntu.

Is there possibility to find all the drivers and install them?

Comment: It's not possible or practical "to find all the drivers and install them". What you should do is edit the question, and add the exact model of HP mini and the Lubunu release number.

Comment: HP Mini (210-1000SA PC), lubuntu 15.04, Driver as much as findible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As in this questoin they might not exist [Can not view fan speed rpm in hp 4530s laptop](https://askubuntu.com/questions/562877/can-not-view-fan-speed-rpm-in-hp-4530s-laptop)

Also what is the cpu useage on your netbooks fan running. Also on my hp pavilion dv 6 1230 us there is a bios option for turning always run fan on or off but the implementation of that is specfic to the netbooks motherboard. I also would see if your cpu useage on your netbook is high and maybe check the temperture and make sure it is not hot. If you turn the fan off during heavy load the laptop might overheat. One convient feature is lxpanel is you can add a temperture monitor to lxpanel by right clicking lxpanel panel settings panel applets and click add and select temperture monitor. However this does require hardware support and does not always work. You can check cpu useage in lxtask which can be started with the keyboard shortcut control alt delete. If you cpu is running hot like 70 or 80 degrees centigrade turing the fan off can cause overheating and damage your hardware.

If you are sure that the fan is running when it should not be under low load and temperture you may want to look into the fan control program but that may not always work.